# what is the proper install order for visual studio 2012 and SQL Server Management Studio 2012 on win7?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I am preparing to do some web development against a SQL Server 2012 server on a fresh install of win 7 x64 development VM.

What should I install first, visual studio or SSMS?

Comment: I've installed both recently onto a new SSD and installed Visual Studio 2012 first followed by SSMS (2008 in my case). Had no problems so far (4 months)

Comment: Why do you think the install order matters?

Comment: [See down the bottom, near "Update"](http://ta.speot.is/2012/04/09/visual-studio-2010-sp1-windows-sdk-7-1-install-order/).

Comment: @wRAR in versions past there were many times I've encountered one clobberimg the other, read many bloposts of how to avoid it, and can never remember which goes first when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither - you can install them in any order. While you do get the occasional question about it in various different forums, I have done this and never had an issue.

SQL does have a Visual Studio dependency (formerly) called BIDS, but Visual Studio can install over/around this no problem.

**Note that this answer is correct when using the initial SQL 2012 release** (as that was the latest edition when this question was asked). Subsequent releases may have changed things. I have made this answer CW to encourage others to edit it as necessary to include info about later versions.

Comment: Actually, this answer is incorrect now with SP1.  I posted the blog article in another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975936/proper-order-of-installation-vs-2012-express-and-sql-server-2012-express/17128836#17128836  In short, install VS2012 first before SQL2012, install service packs, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 11):

This is my favorite order:

1. Windows update before installing anything.
2. SQL Server 2012

   - If you have SP1 integrated with you ISO file, skip to step 4.
   - If you have both SP1 and U5 integrated with your ISO file, skip to step 5
   - Unselect SQL Server Data Tools during installation (step 8 will install the VS 2012 templates instead of these old 2010 ones)
3. SQL Server 2012 [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35575)
4. SQL Server 2012 SP1 [U5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2861107)
5. Visual Studio 2012

   - If you have U3 integrated with you ISO file, skip to step 7.
   - Unselect SQL Server Data Tools during installation because we'll install the updated bits in step 7
6. Visual Studio 2012 [U3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-eg/download/details.aspx?id=39305)
7. SQL Server [Data Tools - BI](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) (adds BI project templates to Visual Studio 2012)
8. SQL Server [Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) (allows you to manage SQL Server 2012 from within visual Studio 2012)
9. Windows Update
10. ReSharper
11. StyleCop
12. SQL ToolBelt

Comment: Well written, great attention to detail.

Comment: Can you please give your reasoning for this? I'm just curious... :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a different way for VMs but on Windows we used to install SQL Server first, as some of the configurations of Visual studio conflict with SQL Server configurations if it was installed before

Comment: Can you tell more about the conflicts?

Comment: @wRAR i cant remember for the moment, i had faced those problems during the colleage a few times. it has been three years i study PHP/Java&Android/Objective C-iOS, so Microsoft may have resolved those problems too i'm not sure..

Comment: I've always had issues. Mainly, the SQL Server Management Studio (tools) won't install if VS is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

No direct dependencies found between the two components, installing Visual Studio first then ensure that .NET Framework installed properly is my approach, then installing SQL Server, but in all cases the SQL Server installation installs the following software components - 2008:

> - NET Framework 3.5
> - SQL Server Native Client
> - SQL Server Setup support files

My approach:

> 1. Visual Studio 2008.
> 2. Visual Studio SP1.
> 3. SQL Server 2008.
> 4. Run Windows updates.

Useful question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473359/visual-studio-and-sql-server-correct-installation-sequence)

Comment: I'm interested in 2012 not 2008, as I will not be using 2008 anything.

Comment: @jmsmcfrlnd - Same approach my friend.