# How to setup environment for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I would like to setup environment on my machine that I would use to learn and test my code in ASP.NET technology. I'm not sure where to start, what I should download first? What I need to test my code? Any information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have currently installed on your computer? Windows? Mac OS? GNU/Linux? If Windows, simply download and install the latest visual studio community edition to get started.

https://beta.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

If you have a more specific question about any step you're stuck with, please edit your question to elaborate on it and the community will try to give a better answer.

Edit: see also [what is the proper install order for visual studio 2012 and SQL Server Management Studio 2012 on win7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046451/what-is-the-proper-install-order-for-visual-studio-2012-and-sql-server-managemen)

My two cents is that if you're learning, it is OK to screw up and start over. Windows 10 allows you to factory reset your computer which is really nice because you typically don't need to find a Windows DVD or something to start over.

Comment: I have Windows 10. I was wondering what should be installed first and how to set database that I can use for testing purpose. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @espresso_coffee look at sql server. Download sql server and read an article on how to attach the db to your project. There are several different approaches. You can use Entitiy framework or ADO.NET, etc...